# How do you select from an array in an order that is not random but is mathematical

Tags: javascript

I can accomplish this without a formula but I am working to create an array selection method that can select at what I would call almost random. The reason being I need to select in a certain as the array grows in powers of 2. The contents of the array indices does not matter.

```
[0] // select index 0
[0,1] // select index 1 then 0
[0,1,2,3] // 3, 1, 2, 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // 7, 3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] // 15,7,11,3,13,5,9,1,14,6,12,4,10,2,8
```

I finally came up with this pattern since it doesn't degrade as the array expands over powers of 2. The selection stays at a constant. This has nothing to do with sorting the arrays but just with selecting pre-sorted arrays in a certain order. I have looked far and wide for possible solutions but it has been a while since I have done serious math which I am sure this needs.

The pattern I can see is not obvious but I will try and explain it more. It has to do with a binary tree. At root you have `[0]`.

```
                     [0]
                    [0,1]
                  [0,1,2,3]
               [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
   // for example
                ___ 20 ___
               /          \
              10          30
            /    \       /    \
           5      15    25    35
          / \    / \    / \   / \
         1   7  12 18  23 27 31  37
```

I need to create a 3rd array that would have the proper order to insert without causing a rebalance.

```
[20,30,10,35,15,25,5,37,18,27,7,31,12,23,1]
```

This selection model continues to grow with the Btree which would cause the tree to not rebalance by inserting these values in a self balancing tree.

Comment: There is no obvious pattern to this as the array shortens in relation to its length!

Comment: I wish I could upload this photo. Its from a bTree. But I will try an explain more.

Comment: What's input and output?  Given an array get an iterator that returns objects for inserting into a btree that doesn't cause a rebalance?

Comment: @DMoses , Contents of the array does not matter. I already have a method to pull out each level and place into an array, they are already sorted by the self balancing tree. I am looking to pick the items from each array to place into a master array that will not cause a tree rebalance on insert of each item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will push a sorted array into another array in an order that would not cause a rebalence if the other array was actually an AVL tree.  It's not the most efficient, but it shows an example of how it can be done.

```js
var sorted = [1, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 23, 25, 27, 30, 31, 35, 37];
console.log("sorted: ", sorted)

function insertBalanced(sortedArray, avlTree) {
  var size = sortedArray.length;
  var result = avlTree;
  var indexesUsed = [];
  function halfIndexes(depth) {
var slices = Math.pow(2, depth);
for(var i = 1; i < slices;i++) {
  var nextIndex = Math.floor(size * i / slices);
  if (!indexesUsed.includes(nextIndex)) {
    indexesUsed.push(nextIndex);
    result.push(sortedArray[nextIndex]);
  }
}
if (indexesUsed.length < size) {
  halfIndexes(depth + 1);
}
  };
  return halfIndexes(1);
}
var someEmptyAvlTree = [];
insertBalanced(sorted, someEmptyAvlTree);
console.log("avlTree", someEmptyAvlTree);
```

Comment: This is nice but not exactly what I am looking for. I am not looking to create an array with items that can be inserted without a rebalance I am looking for a method that can select items from a sorted array in the order I stated above to then push to a master array. I could use this array of values is not a very balanced insertion method of indexes.

Comment: Seems like this method does that.  I mean, you need to re-arrange it a little depending on your needs, if you want to use an iterator next() method or whatnot.

Comment: @mjwrazor I updated the answer to show an example of how you could take the same code and insert into some AVL tree.  I don't actually have an AVL tree implementation so I'm using an array to similate it.

Comment: I think this is a lot closer. I will keep working on it and see if I can get the exact output I am looking for. But I will mark this as the answer if I figure out how to get the particular output from this code. and post my changes below. Or just ask to edit this.

Comment: I found you answer very helpful and could be used as the answer but I went with my own method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a better pattern to fallow that is easier to implement in code. It also does not degrade. I will say DMoses method is also just as relevant. I ended up finding that a pattern of odds and even index rotation helped out.

```
            root             40
                  /                        \
                20                          60 
           /            \              /          \
           10           30           50           70
         /    \       /    \       /    \        /     \
        5     15     25    35     45    55      65     75
       / \   /  \   / \    / \   /  \   /  \   /  \   /  \
      3  7  12  17 23  27 33 37 43  47 52  57 62  67 72  77
```

First separate each row into an array. If pulling from a balanced BTree the arrays will already be sorted least to greatest.

Here is the actual code I used.

```
// array holding all elements
const allArray = [[40],[20,60],[10,30,50,70],[5,15,25,35,45,55,65,75],
                 [3,7,12,17,23,27,33,37,43,47,52,57,62,67,72,77]];
// create sorted reverse index array
const refA = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allArray.length; i++) {
    refA.push([]);
    for(let j = allArray[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        refA[i].push(j);
    }
}
const fillRefA = (prev: number[], current: number[]): number[] => {
    const a = [];
    const prefAOdds = prev.filter((val: number) => (val % 2) !== 0);
    const prefAEvens = prev.filter((val: number) => (val % 2) === 0);
    const currentAOdds = current.filter((val: number) => (val % 2) !== 0);
    const currentAEvens = current.filter((val: number) => (val % 2) === 0);
    const newAOdds = currentAOdds.filter((val: number) => !prefAOdds.includes(val));
    const newAEvens = currentAEvens.filter((val: number) => !prefAEvens.includes(val));

    for (let i = 0; i < prefAOdds.length; i++) {
        a.push(newAOdds[i]);
        a.push(prefAOdds[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < prefAOdds.length; i++) {
        a.push(newAEvens[i]);
        a.push(prefAEvens[i]);
    }
    return a;
};

for (let i = 2; i < refA.length; i++) {
    refA[i] = fillRefA(refA[i - 1], refA[i]);
}
// Then finally put all the arrays into a master array in order of proper insertion.
const final = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < allArray[i].length; j++) {
        final.push(a[i][refA[i][j]]);
    }
}
```

// To explain what is going on here I can show a short index path.

```
//first you cannot work this method on the first item so you need to start at index of 2
// second you have to break evens and odds up but keep the order of previous insertion
[1,0] // odds [1], evens [0]
[3,2,1,0] // odds [3,1], evens [1,0];
// but extract previous array odds and evens 
// so [3], [2]. and you have the previous odds and evens [1], [0]
// and insert them in order, odds then evens. 
[3,1,2,0]
// again with the next row
[7,5] [6,4] [3,1] [2,0]
[7,3,5,1,6,2,4,0] // first you take the current then the previous
// and the next row. 
  [15,13,11,9] [14,12,10,8] [7,3,5,1] [6,2,4,0]
  [15,7,13,3,11,5,9,1,14,6,12,4,10,2,8,0]

// This way no same node is on a branch is filled up before all nodes
// on the row at least have 1 filled then continue filling the leftovers.
// final insertion array
[40,60,20,70,30,50,10,75,35,55,15,65,25,45,5,77,37,67,17,57,27,47,
7,72,33,62,23,52,12,43,3]
```